# How to achieve at-least-once delivery to message-queue while also commiting database transaction? without CDC

Tags: database, transactions, message-queue, acid

I'm looking to achieve at-least-once delivery to message-queue (ex: RabbitMQ) while also committing the transaction in a database (ex: PostgreSQL)

#### Flow

1. Start database transaction
2. Get some data from the database
3. Insert some data into the database
4. If certain conditions apply, publish a message to rabbitMQ
5. Commit the transaction

As you see, if a failure would be to happen after step 4, before step 5, we have published an invalid message.

Even if we retry the whole process, the condition needed for step 4 might not be true anymore, so the previously published message would be even more invalid.

A solution to this would be using CDC, but due to technical cost, it's out of option for now. (I would love to know if there's any cheap to deploy CDC options)

#### Possible solution

Creating an `events` table and inserting desired messages inside of it, then, a cronjob would periodically read from that table and publish unpublished events.

The main issue with this pattern is we would lose the ability of "real-time" message processing, but is this the tradeoff we have to make in order to keep the costs down?

Answer (score 1):

The solution you described is called the [transactional outbox pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html). If you need transactional enqueue then it is the best option if you are tied to database like PostreSQL.

You still can do real time messaging by committing a message to DB and then sending a message directly after committing the transaction. In a naive implementation it is going to duplicate every message. But you can use a cache to perform deduping to reduce the number of duplicates.

IMHO if you are thinking about this issue then you shouldn't really use DB and a queue, but rely on a higher level orchestrator like [temporal.io](https://temporal.io/) that already implements the outbox pattern internally.